# Passing Backbone Model Attributes Using AJAX Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, backbone.js

I'd like to save my Backbone model attributes on the Rails side. My code looks like:

```
var model = this.model.toJSON(); //this.model is my Backbone model
$.ajax({
  url: "/users/" + this.model.get('id'),
  type: "PUT",
  dataType: "json",
  data: model
});
```

For some reason, the attributes are not being saved on the Rails side. I think my problem is: I'm not completely sure what to pass in as the "data" in the AJAX request (JSON, the actual object, etc)?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: You can inspect what you are sending to your backend by a console.log('model is ', model); Then check if your Rails side correctly handles the PUT request, or are there any permission issues. To help debug this in chrome, you can also monitor the network tab in the developers tool to find out what the ajax request is returning (404? 403?)

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with using Backbone's own `save()`? (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)

Comment: try JSON.stringify(model) while passing to data. But i recommend @ivarni on using Backbone model save.

Comment: You can try this for your data attribute:
`data: this.model.attributes`
Because jQuery's ajax data attribute accepts and object and i believe Backbone's `.attributes` returns an object.  Should work.

Comment: Thanks everyone...@PhuPhan was right. I used the data as the model's attributes and set the dataType to "JSON." Also, ideally I can just call 'save()', but my current user model has a urlRoot set to "/session". I'm trying to figure out a way to make it root to "/users"